# Testing findOneAndUpdate upsert duplicate prevention

Tags: node.js, mongodb, testing, mongoose, mean-stack

Hi I have a node js code that uses the findOneAndUpdate with Upsert = true to create a new mongodb document if one does not exist.

I want to test if two async threads simultaneously calls my code then will it create duplicates.

Is that even possible to test? How can I do that. I am a beginner in testing.

Answer (score 0):

> Document Level Concurrency
>
> WiredTiger uses document-level concurrency control for write
>   operations. As a result, multiple clients can modify different
>   documents of a collection at the same time.
>
> For most read and write operations, WiredTiger uses optimistic
>   concurrency control. WiredTiger uses only intent locks at the global,
>   database and collection levels. When the storage engine detects
>   conflicts between two operations, one will incur a write conflict
>   causing MongoDB to transparently retry that operation.
>
> Some global operations, typically short-lived operations involving
>   multiple databases, still require a global “instance-wide” lock. Some
>   other operations, such as dropping a collection, still require an
>   exclusive database lock.

[Document Level Concurrency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#document-level-concurrency)

And in a single collection same _id will never exist _id has a unique index on it, so even if the situation you are explaining occurs, the first query which will get executed will create a new document and the later query will update it.

Comment: With duplication I meant that two documents gets created with separate id and but same data values. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/ check this links paragraph on Upsert and unique index.

Comment: Ok, i thought you are updating by matching _id only. In your case, if the fields you are trying to match for updating are not unique indexed, You may end up with duplicate documents.

Comment: Yes true I have made them unique just wanted to know if I can test it out.